# Angle Brackets in Page head element

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Iam new to ASP.NET with prev. PHP experience (which meaby is causing this problem) and Iam having small problem passing data from codebehind to view-source.

I declared string variable on codebehind side such as:

```
    ...
    public string mystring = "Scotty";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...
```

So now I want to use it in view-code but when I put it in angle brackets (<%: or <%=) and put it in head element I got no access to this value. On the other hand when I put it in BODY element everything is ok. 
My failing example (simplified):

```
 <head runat="server">
   <script language="javascript">
      function beamMeUp()
      {
              alert(<%=mystring;%>);
      }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="javascript:beamMeUp" value="Warp6" />
 </body>
```

Can anyone explain it to me why I can't use it (the <%=mystring;%>) in HEAD but i can use it in BODY ?
Best regards

Answer (score 5):

The semicolon isn't necessary when using `<%=`. Think of it as writing:

```
<% Response.Write(mystring); %>
```

You will want to wrap that in quotes as well.

```
alert("<%=mystring %>");
```

Without quotes would be: `alert(Scotty);`

which does not make much sense unless you have a javascript variable called `Scotty`. 
It should give you an alert box showing `undefined`

The code-behind variable `mystring` is available in the `<head>`. C# IntelliSense isn't displaying for it since it's inside of a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you have

```
<head runat="server">...
```

I believe this causes ASP .NET to construct an HtmlHead object which you can reference from Page.Head.  However, you cannot have inline constructs such as <% .. %> and <%= %> when doing this.  I believe this is also true of other ASP .NET controls such as

`<asp:TreeView ...>
    <asp:TreeViewItem>  <%= will cause error! %> </asp:TreeViewItem
</asp:TreeView>`

http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2007/11/14/code-render-blocks-not-always-work-inside-server-controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You really had three problems:

1.)  You have a javascript error as pointed out by the first responder when he told you to use:

```
alert("<%=mystring %>");
```

2.)  You have an ASP .NET error because you can't use <%= %> inside a tag that has runat="server".

3.) Another javascript error in your onclick assignment.  Note it is better to wire up events in code using attachEvent and addEventListener.  Your onclick assignment does not need the javascript: in front.  You might do this for an href attribute, but not an onclick.  In the onclick, you are already executing javascript.  You could have onclick="alert('yo!')" which would work.  Also, when executing a function, you must include the parenthesis, so you should have onclick="beamMeUp();" (semi colon optional).

Your revised code should look more like:

```
<head>  <!-- notice runat="server" has been removed -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function beamMeUp()
      {
              alert("<%=mystring;%>");
      }
   </script>
</head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="beamMeUp();" value="Warp6" />
 </body>
```

Note:  I tried the code above and it works.  I made these changes

- removed runat="server" from the <head> tag
- added double quotes to alert("<%=mystring;%>");
- changed onclick event to onclick="beamMeUp();" NOT onclick="javascript:beamMeUp".

Good luck.